# SQL Server : select with "Value or All"

Tags: sql-server

I have table `T1` with columns `ID1`, `ID2`.

I need to write one "Select" stored procedure like this

```
Create SP_GetT1ByID1AndID2
    @id1 varchar(50), @id2 varchar(50)
as
begin
    Select * 
    from T1 
    where 
         // If (ID1 = "All" and  ID2 = "All") so we have to return all the data in the table T1
         //  If (ID1 = "All" and ID2 != "All") so we have filter the data according to ID2 
         //  If (ID1 != "All" and ID2 = "All") so we have filter the data according to ID1
         //  If (ID1 != "All" and ID2 != "All") so we have filter the data according to ID1 and ID2
end
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where (@id1 = 'All' or ID1 =  @id1)
  and (@id2 = 'All' or ID2 =  @id2)
```